# Discover queues which messages waiting in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I'd like to detect situation, when there is new message in any queue.

Currently I'm using Management API to list queues with ready messages via `/api/queues/[vhost]` endpoint polling. This works, but API reports data with several-second delay.

Is there any way to poll real-time queues' data or be notified about new message in any queue?

Answer (score 0):

> notified about new message in any queue?

You could consume from the queue with a prefetch value of 1.

Or, you can use the `Basic.Get` method and poll the queue.

In either case, a message will be delivered that you will have to process or reject to re-queue it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be event for new message being published.

Comment: I meant any queue which name I don't know explicitly. Your answer before edit was more relevant, but there is no event to new message being published.

Comment: No, no such event exists, because the expectation is that queues will be consumed from individually.